# Rename build pipeline .yml files in Azure DevOps

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, yaml

I have a .NET Core application that has three build pipelines. (Windows, Linux, macOS)
In each of them, the application gets assembled a little different. This part works so far.

Azure created for each pipeline a .yml file in the root folder of the repository.

- azure-pipelines.yml (Linux Build)
- azure-pipelines-1.yml (Windows Build)
- azure-pipelines-2.yml (macOS Build)

I would like to rename them to something like *azure-pipelines-**platform**.yml*

But when I do so, the configuration in Azure gets broken. I can rename the build configuration, but not the file. And I find no way to configure the link between .yml file and Build config in DevOps

Is it generally not possible to rename the .yml files?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [this Azure Q&A](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/437066/cannot-set-pipeline-name-with-yaml-file-in-azure-d.html) it should be possible to change the name of the yaml file by clicking on "Edit in the visual designer".

Comment: This was it. :) But one should be aware, that this screenshot is old and today it looks very different.

Comment: @NedFlanders Could you add a screenshot? You could choose to post another answer.

Answer (score 6):

As suggested by @030, I have prepared two screenshots that show how to connect the .yml files with the build pipeline.

1. Rename the .yml file in the repository
2. Open the pipeline editor
   [image: Pipeline editor]
3. Select the file from the dropdown
   [image]
4. Select the in step 1 renamed *.yml file and click on `save`.

After the existing .yml is assigned, the pipeline works as before the renaming.

Comment: +1 for adding actual screenshots and the concrete steps.

Answer (score 6):

This has been fixed in recent version of Azure DevOps. Currently you can easily rename or move the pipeline in the list of pipelines while clicking on 3 dots and select Rename/move
[image]

and change your location or move the pipeline
[image]

Comment: this is a useful feature, but it doesn't change what filename the pipeline looks for